# How can I use strlen in php for Persian?

Tags: php, strlen, multibyte, persian

I have this code:

```
$string = 'علی';
echo strlen($string);
```

Since `$string` has **3** Persian characters, output must be **3** but I get **6**.

`علی` has 3 characters. Why my output is **6** ?

How can I use `strlen()` in php for Persian with real output?

Comment: Use [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/mb-strlen) (from MBString extension).

Comment: Your output is 6 because `strlen()` counting bytes without considering  of encoding. In your encoding (UTF8 probably) each character counts as 2 bytes. So, the output for 3 characters will be = 6 (`3 chars * 2 bytes`).

Comment: I ran `var_dump(mb_strlen('علی'));` myself, but the output is still 6 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
function ustrlen($text)
{
    if(function_exists('mb_strlen'))
        return mb_strlen( $text , 'utf-8' );
    return count(preg_split('//u', $text)) - 2;
}
```

it will work for any php version.

Answer (score 20):

Use **[mb_strlen](http://www.php.net/mb_strlen)**

> Returns the number of characters in string str having character encoding (the second parameter) encoding. A multi-byte character is counted as 1.

Since your 3 characters are all multi-byte, you get 6 returned with `strlen`, but this returns `3` as expected.

```
echo mb_strlen($string,'utf-8');
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4ACgSm)**

**Note**

It's important not to underestimate the power of this method and any similar alternatives. For example one could be inclined to say ok if the characters are multi-byte then just get the length with `strlen` and divide it by 2 but that will only work if all characters of your string are multi-byte and even a period `.` will invalidate the count. For example this

```
echo mb_strlen('علی.','utf-8');
```

Returns `4` which is correct. So this function is not only taking the whole length and dividing it by 2, it counts 1 for every multi-byte character and 1 for every single-byte character.

**Note2:**

It looks like you decided not to use this method because `mbstring` extension is not enabled by default for old PHP versions and you might have decided not to try enabling it:) For future readers though, it is not difficult and its advisable to enable it if you are dealing with multi-byte characters as its not only the length that you might need to deal with. **[See Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php)**

Comment: This will still output `3`, you need to pass `encoding` parameter as @Rox mentioned

Answer (score 5):

`mb_strlen` function is your friend

Answer (score 4):

```
$string = 'علی';
echo mb_strlen($string, 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP5, [`iconv_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-strlen.php) can be used (as described in php.net, it returns the character count of a string, so probably it's the best choice):

```
iconv_strlen("علی");
// 3
```

Based on [this answer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#45407) by chernyshevsky@hotmail.com, you can try this:

```
function string_length (string $string) : int {
    return strlen(utf8_decode($string));
}

string_length("علی");
// 3
```

Also, as others answered, you can use [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php):

```
mb_strlen("علی");
// 3
```

#### Notes

- There is a very little difference between them (for illegal latin characters):

  ```
  iconv_strlen("a\xCC\r"); // A notice
  string_length("a\xCC\r"); // 3
  mb_strlen("a\xCC\r"); // 2
  ```
- Performance: `mb_strlen()` is the fastest. Totally, there is no difference between `iconv_strlen()` and `string_length()` at performance. But amazingly, `mb_strlen()` is faster that both about 9 times (as I tested)!